How to static add options for PrimeNG p-dropdown
I would like to static add options for p-dropdown.
<p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
 placeholder="Select options" optionLabel="name"
 (onChange)="onChangeOption()">
 <option *ngFor="let item of items;" [value]="item.value">{{item.label}}</option>
 <option value="null">Others</option>
</p-dropdown>

I have tried to dynamic add the "Others" option at ts file, but I still want to static add like this
Is there any better way to do this ? Tks you all

PrimeNG dropdown doesn't allow rendering the options elements with <option>. It is using the [options] input property. <p-dropdown [options]="items" ...></p-dropdown>. Please refer to the docs.

You cant use option directly in p-dropdown. You have to provide data to options array. For example here variable cities hold the option arrays
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
    <p-dropdown 
        [options]="cities" 
        [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" 
        optionLabel="name"
        placeholder="Select a City" />
</div>

if you don't want to provide it from controller class then you can directly pass the array in HTML itself like this
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
        <p-dropdown 
            [options]="[{name: 'Australia', code: 'AU'},{name: 'Brazil', code: 'BR'}]" 
            [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" 
            optionLabel="name"
            placeholder="Select a City" />
    </div>

